# How to pass data from form to method (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning how to create and handle a form in Rails + HAML.

My view looks like so:

```
= form_tag sessions_path do
    = text_field_tag :username, ""
    = password_field_tag :password, ""
    = submit_tag "log in"
```

It gives this html:

```
...
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="WWg2IuLNo+7VZFIpOAFaUJseF7YCn2xiVcieI6zJGx4=" /></div>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" />
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="log in" />
</form>
...
```

My create method looks like this:

```
   def create
    render "myview"
   end
```

Basically I don't know how to access in method the data that was filled in to the form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not informative. Can you provide some more info. about what you want to do?

Anyway you can do this:

```
  <% form_tag url_for(:action => 'method_name', :param_name => "abc" )
     ...
  <% end %>
```

In controller:

```
  def method_name
    p = params[:param_name]
  end
```